# Update Author name In Sharepoint using Rest Api

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to update Author Name of a file in Sharepoint using Rest api. I can retrieve the  author name of a file using the url "_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('Foldername')/Files('Filename')?$select=Author/Title&$expand=Author". Is there a way to update the Author name of a file  using rest api call? The file  is present in a particular folder and the  folder is present under Shared documents.

Answer (score 0):

I tested to update Author field using the Rest API below, it turns out for system field "Author", it's not available to update.

Even set "ReadOnlyField" to false, still not able to update:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var properties = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem" },
    'Title':'TestTitle',
    'AuthorId': 27  //Another User Id 
};
var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/sites/dev/shared%20documents')/Files('Test2019.txt')/ListItemAllFields";
updateJson(requestUrl,properties)
.done(function(data){
   console.log('List item has been updated'); 
})
.fail(function(error){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
})

function updateJson(url,payload)
{
   return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
         "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
         "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
         "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
         "If-Match": "*"
      }
   });    
}
</script>
```

For other normal person field, it's working.

In Summary, per the test result, the Author field can't be updated.